# Advantage and disadvantage of using void pointer in C++ pimpl

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I am trying to study the pimpl technique for C++. After went through some articles online, I found there are two different ways for pimpl, one is

```
class X
{
  public:
    X(...parameters...)
    ~X()
  private:
    struct Impl;
    Impl* impl_;
};
```

The other way is to use a raw void pointer, like

```
class X
{
  public:
    X(...parameters...)
    ~X()
  private:
    void * impl_;
};
```

Then use static_cast to cast the void pointer back to the original type.

***What are the advantages and disadvantages comparing these two ways?***

Thanks!

Comment: first is always better as it preserves the type information

Comment: There is no advantage to using a void pointer, only disadvantages.  If you want to hide the declaration of the implementation-class, use a forward declaration instead; that will let the compiler know the class exists (so that you don't get a syntax error), while still allowing you to keep all of the details hidden away inside the .cpp file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use `void*` for implementing a pimpl, or for much of anything for that matter. It provides no benefits; and has the potential problem where if you `static_cast` to the wrong type for some reason, you will have undefined behaviour.

It's easy to forward-declare your implementation class, as you have in your first example. That is the correct way to implement a pimpl.

Answer (score 1):

With the first one, using a debugger you will be able to view the impl pointer and it's data members values. If you have a `void*` pointer, you won't be able to do that.The second option doesn't offer any advantage that I know of.

Either way, if you have

```
Impl* GetImpl() { return impl_; }
```

or

```
Impl* GetImpl() { return static_cast<Impl*>(impl_); }
```

Both functions will generate exactly the same assembly code.

If you don't need a getter, you could instead have it like:
`struct Impl* impl_;` as well.

Comment: @M.M or c-style cast?

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov that would be valid, although as a rule it's a good idea to use the "least strong" cast that does the job, to reduce the chance of accidentally casting to the wrong type bypassing compiler errors

Comment: @M.M, no, I mean what code a compiler will generate? I doubt it will use a `reinterpret_cast` sledgehammer as a first choice

Comment: Oh right, Yeah the C-style cast will resolve to `static_cast` if that is a valid cast.  In this case `reinterpret_cast` is the same, I just advised to use `static_cast` according to the smaller hammer principle

Comment: If `impl_` is `void*` there no reason to use anything other than `static_cast`. Not sure why anyone would even consider a C style cast for converting pointers in C++. Meh.